# NetBeans 12.3 - Code completion and code suggestion very slow

Tags: netbeans

All of a sudden the code completion and suggestion (for example when typing the `.` operator listing the possible methods on an object, etc.) is very slow, also fixing imports. Restarting the IDE didn't solve it.

I cannot see any other task `NetBeans` is running.
What can be the cause?
Is it because the update to `12.4` is coming up and `NetBeans` gathers some data or metrics :)

Otherwise the IDE is working normal, quick as usual.

Comment: You need to provide more information than that, and address some obvious questions arising for your issue. For example...Does the problem persist if you restart your machine? You say that this performance issue has arisen "all of a sudden", so are you certain it is not caused by completely unrelated resource usage on your machine, and if so, how do you know that? Does this issue arise every time you use code completion, or only occasionally, or have you only seen it happen once? Have you checked resource usage on your machine? Have you checked the NetBeans log for any unusual messages? etc...

Comment: Please define "complition."

Comment: Check Tools > Options > Editor > Code Completion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if the performance is same when you deactivate your antivirus
2. Check in the About window of NetBeans where your cache directory is located and rename/delete it
3. You can try it with most recent release 12.4. It's not yet published on their website but you can download it anyway: https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/netbeans/netbeans/12.4/netbeans-12.4-bin.zip

Comment: No Antivirus running, using Ubuntu. The directory you mentioned is 4.4 GB large, but just the folder mavenindex is 4.0 GB.

Comment: Deleted the directory and now it is much faster, normal in fact. What was wrong with that directory?

Comment: It contains as you already mentioned the maven index and some other indices regarding the code completion. But I don't know any details tbh.